# Can I combine these two almost identical MERGE statements into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a feeling I've spent too much time on this problem and have been blinded... and hopefully a pair of fresh eyes can help point out a simple error!

This is the `MERGE` statement I *think* should work:

**Not working:**

```
MERGE assignment_tbl AS target
USING (SELECT 1 s) AS source
ON target.id = @id
   AND target.id1 = @id1
   AND target.id2 = @id2
WHEN matched AND NOT (target.iFeeScope = @iFeeScope OR target.nFeeAmount = @nFeeAmount) AND (target.bActive = 1) THEN
  UPDATE SET target.dLastUpdated = @dNow,
             target.dDisabled = @dNow,
             target.bActive = 0;
```

The problem is in my `WHEN matched AND NOT` statement: `(target.iFeeScope = @iFeeScope OR target.nFeeAmount = @nFeeAmount)`, and the only way around this I've found is to break the statement up into two separate (and almost identical) blocks:

**Working (but inefficient):**

```
MERGE assignment_tbl AS target
USING (SELECT 1 s) AS source
ON target.id = @id
   AND target.id1 = @id1
   AND target.id2 = @id2
WHEN matched AND NOT (target.iFeeScope = @iFeeScope) AND (target.bActive = 1) THEN
  UPDATE SET target.dLastUpdated = @dNow,
             target.dDisabled = @dNow,
             target.bActive = 0;

MERGE assignment_tbl AS target
USING (SELECT 1 s) AS source
ON target.id = @id
   AND target.id1 = @id1
   AND target.id2 = @id2
WHEN matched AND NOT (target.nFeeAmount = @nFeeAmount) AND (target.bActive = 1) THEN
  UPDATE SET target.dLastUpdated = @dNow,
             target.dDisabled = @dNow,
             target.bActive = 0;
```

What do I need to change in my original statement to achieve the result of the following two statements?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own... figured it was an issue with the AND/NOT logic!

```
MERGE assignment_tbl AS target
USING (SELECT 1 s) AS source
ON target.id = @id
   AND target.id1 = @id1
   AND target.id2 = @id2
   AND target.bActive = 1
WHEN matched AND (NOT (target.iFeeScope = @iFeeScope)) 
             OR (NOT (target.nFeeAmount = @nFeeAmount)) THEN
  UPDATE SET target.dLastUpdated = @dNow,
             target.dDisabled = @dNow,
             target.bActive = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
WHEN matched AND target.iFeeScope != @iFeeScope AND target.nFeeAmount != @nFeeAmount AND (target.bActive = 1) THEN
```

Comment: That works out the same as my original code, but thanks. I've answered with the solution.